# generic/include/config/rds/rdma.h': Not a directory

Tags: apt, package-management, xubuntu, dpkg, linux-headers

I need help with Ubuntu 16.04

I can't install any programs, or even do a system upgrade.

```
$ sudo apt install -f

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 7.325 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 260709 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic (4.4.0-51.72) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic/include/config/rds/rdma.h': Not a directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Removing headers

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove linux-headers-4.4.0-51 linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic

dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove linux-headers-4.4.0-51 which isn't installed
(Reading database ... 260709 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic (4.4.0-51.72) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic (--remove):
 unable to securely remove '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic/include/config/rds/rdma.h': Not a directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic
```

---

```
$ df -i

Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            489035    505  488530    1% /dev
tmpfs           494061    663  493398    1% /run
/dev/sda1      7077888 363740 6714148    6% /
tmpfs           494061     21  494040    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           494061      5  494056    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           494061     16  494045    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           494061     41  494020    1% /run/user/1000
```

---

```
$ df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           386M  6,1M  380M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       107G   11G   91G  11% /
tmpfs           1,9G  3,9M  1,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           386M   92K  386M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: The simple way is to reinstall (`sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic`), then try removing again.

Comment: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: That's a catch-all error code. We need to know the details, usually on the line above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did it

Delete headers

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic
```

Reinstall headers

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic
```

That's all that was needed.